# Regex expression to search all files and subdirectories for expression and return only the first line of match

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression utility that will search through a specified directory and return only the first line of each file, or a special 13 digit number on the first line.

Is there a simple and effective way to do this in a regex in c# or vb.net or vb6?
The code I'm trying to search for is this:000999D5, but the 13 digit number I want to return is only on the first line.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: do you need this as a part of application, or you do some administrative task and arranging files? I can think of a way to do this in Cygwin shell as a one-liner script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine a readily available API request to do this, so you'll have to code this yourself. Nothing too fancy here.

```
public class ScanDirectory
{
    public void WalkDirectory(string directory)
    {
        WalkDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(directory));
    }

    private void WalkDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        // Scan all files in the current path
        foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            // Do something with each file.
        }

        DirectoryInfo [] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();

        // Scan the directories in the current directory and call this method 
        // again to go one level into the directory tree
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            WalkDirectory(subDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

(Code is from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ScanDirectory.aspx)

And in every file you'll have to read a first line. You can do this with

```
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
String firstLine = file.ReadLine();
if (null != firstLine)
{
  // do regexp comparison
}
```

Regex comparison should look like this:

```
    string input = "0123456789132";

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([0-9]{13})",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
           // DO your stuff
    }
```

Probably you'll need to change regexp to match your exact requirements, as they are not very clear at the moment.